# What does the "Allow employers to see your resume in searches" option in Job application form do?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not sure what value does the option "Allow employers to see your resume in searches" brings to the user. Can someone please explain the purpose?

[image]

Comment: The purpose seems self-explanatory. What exactly are you confused about? The advantage is, if employers can see your resume during searches, they'll be able to contact you about positions.

Comment: I think I can see the confusion. I guess the settings on "Resume" section are not specific to the employer you're applying, but instead are actually general preferences. Meaning, after you apply to that specific employer, your uploaded resume will be available to *all* employers on SO Jobs when searching for future candidates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are making/uploading a resume while applying for a position, the checkbox asks if you'd like that same resume to be searchable, so that other potential employers may contact you if they feel like your resume is a good fit with their positions.

Comment: I agree. But, should the candidate has to choose to allow it? My opinion is by default it should be available for the employers, isn't it?

Comment: @KarthikAMR It will be available by default to the employer you apply for, that employer is the only one you have implicitly agreed to share your resume with, because you are actively applying for a job with them. It is definitely possible that you would not want your CV shared with everyone (because, for example, your current employer might be on SO Careers and you don't necessarily want to let them know you're looking for another job just yet)